# Seg fault due to strcpy and strcat

Tags: c, string

Why do I get segfualt in the code below? I expect it to print the first word "hey". I know there are other ways to do what I am trying to do, but I wonder why this fails. Please help.

```
int main(){
    char string[30], ops1[30], temp;
    char t[2];
    int op1, i=0;
    strcpy(string, "hey ssup");
    while(string[i] != '\0') {
        if(string[i]!= ' '){
            temp = string[i];
            strcpy(ops1, &temp);
            i++;
            while(string[i] != ' ') {
                temp = string[i];
                strcpy(t, &temp);
                strcat(ops1, t);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s", ops1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `strcpy(ops1, &temp);`, `&temp` is not a pointer to a null-terminated string.

Comment: Please add motivation for what this does and why.  Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Why do you need this `strcpy` at all?

Comment: For minimal changes, I suggest making `temp` a 2 char array and set `temp[1] = '\0';` to null-terminate it. (Other code changes involving `temp` are required after changing it to an array, but those should be pretty obvious.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `strcpy()` and `strcat()` in case of single character . You can directly copy by help of **index** like `ops1[j] = string[i];`.

Also you forget to add `ops1[j] = '\0';` string terminator. You need to specify `\0` to end a string.

Your `while(string[i] != ' ')` will not end `(is an infinite loop)` because `i` is not changing in that loop. This problem can be solved with help of a single loop.

Try this code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char string[30], ops1[30];
    char t[2];
    int op1, i, j;
    strcpy(string, "hey ssup");

    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0')
    {
        ops1[j++] = string[i]; // coping

        if (string[i] == ' ')  // stops when first ' ' found
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    ops1[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s", ops1);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
hey
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I knew this way is better. But I couldn't figure out what goes wrong with my code.

Answer (score -1):

**you are getting seg fault because of the second while loop, correct code is below**

```
    int main()

    {

    char string[30], ops1[30], temp;
    char t[2];
    int  i=0;
    strcpy(string, "hey ssup");
    while(1) 
      {
        if(string[i]!= ' ')
          {
            temp = string[i];
            strcpy(&ops1[i], &temp);


           }    
       else
         {
          ops1[i]='\0';
        break;
           }
        i++;

         }
    printf("%s\n", ops1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(&ops1[i], &temp)` is just as wrong here as in the original question.

Comment: @mlp Can you tell me the error in this cause it prints correct output.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. But if "string" is scanned instead of hard-coding it, it seg  faults again. I guess it has to do something with the compiler.

Comment: I don't think so ...you can use scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string) for scanning a string and it will work perfectly.

Comment: The second argument to `strcpy()` must be a pointer to a NUL-terminated array of `char`; `&temp` is *not* such a thing.